# What does SDL_GetError say in the case of an error?

Tags: c, terminal, sdl, sdl-2

My main question: Please may you list a few examples of what `SDL_GetError` would print?

I want to use `SDL_GetError` to help me debug, however I don't know what to expect or how to create my own intentional errors. 
The libsdl wiki says:

> The message is only applicable when an SDL function has signaled an
>   error. You must check the return values of SDL function calls to determine 
>   when to appropriately call SDL_GetError().

however http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GetError says:

> Although this example uses SDL_Init, SDL_GetError provides an error
>   message for any failed SDL operation.

so which is it? Only some or all? None of the SDL wikis/documentations I have seen give a list of example error messages, so I don't know how to initiate an error, or what to expect in terms of content and format. Is

> Error in `./foo': double free or corruption (top):

an `SDL_GetError` message or is that caused by something else?

Comment: I'm almost sure `double free or corruption` is not an SDL error. *"None of the SDL wikis/documentations I have seen give a list of example error messages"* You could simply `grep` for `SDL_SetError` in SDL source and see all the error messages SDL uses.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm using a university computer, I don't know how to find the SDL source

Comment: You can download it from SDL site.

Comment: It is intended to be any human readable message that could better explain why requested operation have failed. There is no "format" for human readable messages. You can grep source as HolyBlackCat said, but I really don't see why that could be important at all. "Double free or corruption" looks like libc memory allocator failure, most likely to memory stomping (or indeed double-freeing the same address).

Answer (score 0):

[The wiki entry for `SDL_Error`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Error) lists the error strings:

> SDL_errorcode | The corresponding error string
>
> ---
>
> SDL_ENOMEM | Out of memory
>
> SDL_EFREAD | Error reading from datastream
>
> SDL_EFWRITE | Error writing to datastream
>
> SDL_EFSEEK | Error seeking in datastream
>
> SDL_UNSUPPORTED | Unknown SDL error
>
> SDL_LASTERROR | Unknown SDL error
>
> any other value | Unknown SDL error

See also [SDL_error.c](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/master/src/SDL_error.c). One of the wiki entries seems to be incorrect. The correct error code - error string pair would be:

> SDL_UNSUPPORTED | That operation is not supported

You can set custom errors messages with `SDL_SetError` - see the `.c` above. Finally, "double free or corruption" is not an error caused by SDL, but most likely by a double free. I suggest gdb/valgrind to debug it.